# JSON to CSV in python convert issue

Tags: python, arrays, json, object, csv

I am trying to convert a nested JSON object file into CSV.
Here is the sample of JSON

```js
{
   "total_hosts" : [
      {
         "TYPE" : "AGENT",
         "COUNT" : 6
      }
   ],
   "installed" : [
      {
         "ID" : "admin-4.0",
         "VERSION" : 4,
         "ADDON_NAME" : "Administration"
      },
      {
         "ID" : "admin-2.0",
         "VERSION" : 2,
         "ADDON_NAME" : "Administration"
      },
      {
         "ID" : "ch-5.0",
         "VERSION" : "5",
         "ADDON_NAME" : "Control Host"
      }
   ],
   "virtual_machine" : [
      {
         "COUNT" : 4,
         "TYPE" : "VM"
      }
```

TYPE,COUNT,ID,VERSION like these are columns but the problem is not each object have values in it some have 1 object with these values or some have more so,I write in row , so i am trying to write blank space when there is no value for that column.

the code to write it into CSV

```
json_input = open('all.json')
try:
    decoded = json.load(json_input)
# tell computer where to put CSV
    outfile_path='Path to CSV'
# open it up, the w means we will write to it
    writer = csv.writer(open(outfile_path,'w'))


       for index in range(len(decoded['installed'])):
            row = []

            if decoded['total_hosts'][index]['TYPE'] is None:
                row.append(str(''))
            else:
                row.append(str(decoded['total_hosts'][index]['TYPE']))
            if decoded['total_hosts'][index]['COUNT'] is None:
                row.append(str(''))
            else:
                row.append(str(decoded['total_hosts'][index]['COUNT']))

            writer.writerow(row)
```

I am getting `Index out of range` error , I even tried `True`/`False` condition for `if`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Updated : Expected Output :

```
TYPE,COUNT,ID,VERSION,ADDON_NAME,COUNT,TYPE
AGENT,6,admin-4.0,4,Administration,4,VM
 , ,admin-2.0,2,Administration, , 
 , ,cd-5.0,5,Control Host, ,
```

So basically i need blank spaces when there is no value for that column.

Quesion Modified : OUTPUT :

```
AGENT,6,,,
 , ,admin-4.0,4,Administration
 , ,admin-2.0,2,Administration
 , ,ch-5.0,5,Control Host
```

Expected OUTPUT :

```
AGENT,6,admin-4.0,4,Administration
 , ,admin-2.0,2,Administration
 , ,ch-5.0,5,Control Host
```

Updated : I even tried

```
            row.append(str(entry.get('TYPE', '')))
            row.append(str(entry.get('COUNT', '')))
            row.append(str(entry.get('ID', '')))
            row.append(str(entry.get('VERSION', '')))
            row.append(str(entry.get('ADDON_NAME', '')))
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Still got the same output as above. :(

Comment: Your `installed`, and `total_hosts` lists don't have the same *length*; you are looping over `range(len(decoded['installed']))` but then use the index in the `decoded['total_hosts']` and `decoded['_hosts']` lists (the latter is probably a typo).

Comment: you should include a complete example of input and expected output.

Comment: Yes it was typo :) Actually i want to loop it for all the elements in the file , but as they are separate objects/Arrays so i took array with maximum number elements and loop through it, And that's why i put IF condition so if there is no value it should append blank space. so i can maintain the column structure.

Comment: @user3520135: it's the `decoded['total_hosts'][index]` operation that throws the exception, no trying to access `['TYPE']` (which would throw a `KeyError` exception instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes here:

1. You use the length of `decoded['installed']` to generate an index you then use for the `decoded['total_hosts']` list. This will generate index errors because `decoded['total_hosts']` doesn't have as many entries.
2. Accessing a key that doesn't exist will throw a `KeyError`; use the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) instead to retrieve a value or a default.

It's much simpler to just loop *directly* over a list, no need to generate an index:

```
for host in decoded['total_hosts']:
    row = [host.get('TYPE', ''), host.get('COUNT', '')]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

You can extend this to handle more than one key:

```
for key in ('total_hosts', 'installed', 'virtual_machine'):
    for entry in decoded[key]:
        row = [entry.get('TYPE', ''), entry.get('COUNT', '')]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

If you needed to *combine* the output of two entries, use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to pair up the lists, using a default value for when the shorter list runs out:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

for t, i, v in izip_longest(decoded['total_hosts'], decoded['installed'], decoded['version'], fillvalue={}):
    row = [t.get('TYPE', ''), t.get('COUNT', ''), 
           i('ID', ''), i('VERSION', ''), i.get('ADDON_NAME', ''),
           v.get('COUNT', ''), v.get('TYPE', '')]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

This allows for any one of the three lists to be shorter than the others.

For Python versions before 2.6 (which added `itertools.izip_longest`) you'd have to assume that `installed` was always longest, and then use:

```
for i, installed in decoded['installed']:
    t = decoded['types'][i] if i < len(decoded['types']) else {}
    v = decoded['version'][i] if i < len(decoded['version']) else {}
    row = [t.get('TYPE', ''), t.get('COUNT', ''), 
           installed['ID'], installed['VERSION'], installed['ADDON_NAME'],
           v.get('COUNT', ''), v.get('TYPE', '')]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: @user3520135: that error usually indicates you forgot a closing `)` or `]` on the preceding line.

Comment: @user3520135: note, the `row = []` line is entirely redundant.

Comment: Yes you were right, Thanks again but there is one small problem.

Comment: @user3520135: you didn't specify you wanted to *merge* the `total_hosts` and `installed` lists; what happens if there are more than one `total_hosts` entry?

Comment: Sorry about that, i am trying to get out put in column,row format so if there are any more values it will get written in it's corresponding column, if not there will be blank space.

Comment: @user3520135: Are you using Python 2 or 3 here?

Comment: I am using Python V2.4

Comment: @user3520135: ah, that's *ancient* by now. No option to upgrade to Python 2.6 or newer at all?

Comment: Could you please tell me How will that help for this issue?

Comment: @user3520135: Then we can use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to merge the two lists. It makes the code vastly simpler.